# Access Arguments to Parent Task from Subtask in Celery

Tags: python, celery

Is it possible to access the arguments with which a parent task A was called, from its child task Z? Put differently, when Task Z gets called in a chain, can it somehow access an argument *V* that was invoked when Task A was fired, *but that was not passed through any intermediary nodes between tasks A and Z*? And if so, how?

Using Celery 3.0 with RabbitMQ for results backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to provisionally answer my own question with a "no" -- and the hopes that someone more knowledgeable than me will come back with a solution.

After looking more closely at the Celery documentation, I'm thinking that there simply isn't a way to access the arguments with which a parent task was called.  According to the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#states):

> During its lifetime a task will transition through several possible
>   states, and each state may have arbitrary metadata attached to it.
>   When a task moves into a new state the previous state is forgotten
>   about..

A task can be in one of the following states: Pending, Started, Success, Failure, Retry, and Revoked.   For my scenario, the key here would, it seems, be the Success state. What I want to do is, for a given succeessful task, locate the id of (one of its) parent task(s), and then view the arguments with which the parent was called.  However, according to the documentation, a task in the SUCCESS state will not contain this sort of data (since the parent task itself will have been successful insofar as it has spawned a child task):

> SUCCESS Task has been successfully executed.
>
> metadata: result contains the return value of the task.
>   propagates:   Yes ready:  Yes

In other words, it would seem that there's a hard limit here.  Even if I can locate the ID of the parent task I'm interested in, because it has successfully executed, I will by definition not be able to access the arguments with which it was called because it only contains the return value (no longer its arguments).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, at least in `chord`. When you `bind=True` your task, you can access `self.request`. In `self.request.chord` You can find a detailed dict. In its `kwargs` or `options['chord']` you will find what you're looking for, but it's not an elegant solution. Also, if the parent has been replaced, you will only be able to see the final state.